# How to check the number of characters in gcp text to speech

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to check how many characters I have used so far this month on the GCP text to speech API?
We are able to use up to 4 million characters per month for free and would like to use as much of the free quota as possible.

I checked the GCP console but could not find any pertinent information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: On [text to speech quotas page](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/quotas) there is a link to [Monitoring API usage](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/monitoring). Maybe this is a place to check?